# as3: reference to array by string (name of var)?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, adobe, air

is it possible to create a **new reference to an array by using it's varname** ?

e.g.

```
private var _myArray:Array = new Array("a","m","d");

...

  function getReference(_varName:String):void
  {

    trace(_varName)//_myArray

    //ok, let's try to create the reference:
    var _reference:Array = Class(getDefinitionByName(_varName)) as Array;

    trace(_myArray.length)//3
    trace(_reference.length)//0

  }

...
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
private var _myArray:Array = new Array("A","B","C");

...

  function getReference(_varName:String):void
  {

    trace(this[_varName].length)//3    
  }
```

...

Answer (score 0):

It's possible.
I think the name of definition is not correct,
you may use the full definition of the class like 'flash.display.xxx' or the class you defined.
This is the reference
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/package.html#getDefinitionByName%28%29